# Can we use equals() method to compare all content in an object?

Tags: java, oop, equals

I tried to perform a comparison between two objects of the same class. Actually, I wanted to compare the content of the both the objects. Here, the objects are of class Student. In class Student I have defined a static method called `equals()` as shown below.
By doing so, will my intention be accomplished (compare the names and birthdays of both students)? If not what is happening here?
The problem is that I don't get the answer I expect. The output is `false` even though it must be `true`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student("John", "Johnny");
        Student b = new Student("John", "Johnny");
        a.setBirthDate(10, 10, 10);
        b.setBirthDate(10, 10, 10);
        boolean ans = Student.equals(a, b);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

}
```

```
public class Date {
    public int day;
    public int month;
    public int year;
    
    public Date(int d, int m, int y) {
        this.day = d;
        this.month = m;
        this.year = y;
    }
}
```

```
public class Student{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;
    
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public void setBirthDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        Date b_day = new Date(day, month, year);
        birthDate = b_day;
    }
    public static boolean equals(Student a, Student b) {
            if (a.equals(b)) { //is this comparison wrong?
            return true;
        }

        return false;
        
    }
}
```

Later, I modified the `equals()` method as follows too. But still the output is `false` though it must be `true`.

```
public static boolean equals(Student a, Student b) {
        //we cannot use == operator because this operator compares the references (memory locations) of a and b rather than their content. Therefore, the best option is to use equals(Object obj) method.
        //however, in the case of String comparison below, since the 'new' operator is not used, there's no problem in using either(because of string pool)
        if (a.firstName.equals(b.firstName) && a.lastName.equals(b.lastName) && a.birthDate.equals(b.birthDate)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
        
    }
```

Please can you tell me what's wrong with my implementation of the `equals()` method in both the scenarios depicted above.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**

I have overridden the equals method now as follows. But still I face the same issue. I suspect that there's something wrong with the `Date` class. But the problem is that I'm not quite sure of it. Also, I don't understand how to remedy the problem. Can someone please tell me what's wrong here.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object student) {
        System.out.println(this.firstName);
        System.out.println(this.lastName);
        System.out.println(this.birthDate);
        
        System.out.println(((Student)student).firstName);
        System.out.println(((Student)student).lastName);
        System.out.println(((Student)student).birthDate);
        return super.equals(student);
        
    }
```

Comment: In your first example, you call the equals method on the Student object, which is not overridden by you, so it takes the default implementation from Object. If you override the equals method Object.equals properly, then your first example should already work. And then you don't need that static equals method anyway, because a.equals(b) would just give you the boolean response.

Comment: ...and override `equals(Object)` in `Date` too.

Comment: Writing equals method is actually more tricky than it seems. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java). In general you should also overwrite HashCode as well. Right now your code fails because dates are compared by address, and not by their content. You can fix it quickly by overwriting equals method in Date.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I override the above method?

Comment: Your static method doesn't override the equals() method and should not be named that. Equals should have the signature: ``public boolean equals(Object o)``.